# Two Seq Comparison in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is a scenario of determining updated data in a data update. A Seq of case class objects have their IDs and the case class has an override equals method which makes a data comparison of its attributes excluding the ID field. To find out any updated data entries, I need to retrieve the data from DB. And a comparison of two sequences is needed. What is a Scala approach to find out any objects which are updated?

Just having a thought: creating a map with the object ID as the key and the object as its value. That might work.

(Update) Here is a solution I come out

```
val existingDataList: Foo = ...
val existingDataMap: Map[Long, Foo] = existingDataList.map(d => d.id -> d)(collection.breakOut)

// To find out updated data    
val updatedData = inputData.filter(d => existingDataMap.get(d.id) != d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have two collections, and you want to find pairs of objects in them, having the same ids, but different data, right?  `diff` isn't really what you want here.

Something like this will do it:

```
(first ++ second)
  .groupBy (_.id)
  .mapValues (_.toSet)
  .filterNot { case (_, v) => v.size != 2 }
  .values
  .map { v => v.head -> v.last }
```

It will give you a list of tuples like (first, second), where both elements have the same id, but different data.

This assumes that you ids are unique within each collection, and that each id appears in both collections.

Alternatively, if you can guarantee that the collections are of the same size, and contain exactly the same set of ID's, you could do something like this, which is less efficient, but a bit simpler:

```
     first.sortBy(_.id)
       .zip(second.sortBy(_.id))
       .filterNot { case (a, b) => a == b }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a couple advanced Scale approaches.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you right, you've already done the most of the hard work by overriding `equals` - and of course you **MUST** also override `hashCode` correspondingly e.g.:

```
case class Thing(id:Long, foo:String, bar:Int) {
  override def equals(that:Any):Boolean = {
    that match {
      case Thing(_, f, b) => (f == this.foo) && (b == this.bar)
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  override def hashCode:Int = {
    // A quick hack. You probably shouldn't do this for real; 
    // set id to 0 and use the default hashing algorithm:
    ScalaRunTime._hashCode(this.copy(id = 0))
  }
}
```

Now we define a few `Thing` instances:

```
val t1 = Thing(111, "t1", 1)
val t1c = Thing(112, "t1", 1) // Same as t1 but with a new ID
val t2 = Thing(222, "t2", 2)
val t3 = Thing(333, "t3", 3)
val t4 = Thing(444, "t4", 4)
val t4m = Thing(444, "t4m", 4)  // Same as t4 but with a modified "foo"
```

Let's make a couple of sequences:

```
val orig = Seq(t1, t2, t3, t4)
val mod = Seq(t1c, t2, t3, t4m)
```

And now a [`diff`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq) tells us everything we need to know:

```
mod.diff(orig)
// => returns Seq(t4m) - just what we wanted
```

Comment: That will work. And yes, I also wrote the hashCode method.